# For loops not working completely right Lua

Tags: lua

```lua
for amountofspinstodo = 1, 100 do
    local pick = math.random( 1, #box.CONTENTS )
    local rarity = INV:CalculateItemRarity()
    local ITEMPICK = INV:GetDataFromName(box.CONTENTS[pick])
    local RARITYS_OF_ITEM_PICK = ITEMPICK.RARITYS
    if has_value(RARITYS_OF_ITEM_PICK, rarity)then
        tbl.spintable[amountofspinstodo] = { NAME = box.CONTENTS[pick], RARITY = rarity }
        print(amountofspinstodo)
    else
        amountofspinstodo = amountofspinstodo - 1
        print(amountofspinstodo)
    end
end
```

I made this for loop to check if an item has a certain rarity, and if it does then allow it to be an item, but also if it does not have the rarity then it is supposed to make the for loop do that one again, until every item is picked. However when i run the for loop it does this and i have no idea why.

[Here is the console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIdYZ.png)

Some of the numbers are duplicates such as 48 and 48 which should be 48 and 49.

Any help would be appreciated!

-Thanks D12

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Technically, your code is doing what you've told it to do, subtract 1 from `amountofspins` if the rarity doesn't match. But if `amountofspins` is to match the number of items in the table, you're better off with `print(#tbl.spintable)`. Additionally, I think you might consider `table.insert(tbl.spintable, {...})` instead of how you're doing it now.

Comment: Looks like you missed the start of the for loop in the code you posted, can you include that?

Comment: @Nifim sorry about that, i have added it now.

Comment: You can not change the loop iterator value from inside a for loop, you will want to use a while loop instead

Answer (score 5):

`amountofspinstodo` can not be changed from inside your for loop, and persist to the next run of the loop.

References:

> Third, you should never change the value of the control variable: The effect of such changes is unpredictable. If you want to break a for loop before its normal termination, use break. - [*Programming in Lua: 4.3.4 – Numeric for*](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html)

here is a simple example you can use to see:

```
for i = 1, 10 do
    print(i) 
    i = 10
end
```

Instead you should use a while loop:

```
local amountofspinstodo = 1
while(amountofspinstodo < 100) do
    local pick = math.random( 1, #box.CONTENTS )
    local rarity = INV:CalculateItemRarity()
    local ITEMPICK = INV:GetDataFromName(box.CONTENTS[pick])
    local RARITYS_OF_ITEM_PICK = ITEMPICK.RARITYS
    if has_value(RARITYS_OF_ITEM_PICK, rarity)then
        tbl.spintable[amountofspinstodo] = { NAME = box.CONTENTS[pick], RARITY = rarity }
        print(amountofspinstodo)
        amountofspinstodo = amountofspinstodo + 1
    else
        print(amountofspinstodo)
    end
end
```

Comment: Do you mean _"can not"_ or _"should not?"_

Comment: can not, simple example: `for i = 1, 10 do print(i);  i = 10; end`

Comment: [The documentation](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html) specifically cautions against this: _"[...] you should never change the value of the control variable: The effect of such changes is unpredictable."_ In practice, it looks like you can change the variable all you want in the body... but changes will be discarded for the following iteration.

Comment: @canon Thank you i was looking for the exact piece of documentation to include in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As Nifim [already pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59847893/4984564) out, you can't.

But looking at your code, it becomes clear that you're actually trying to do two actual loops in one for loop, which obviously doesn't work.

Moving your code around a bit, you get:

```lua
for spins = 1, 100 do
    local pick, rarity
    repeat
        pick = math.random( 1, #box.CONTENTS )
        rarity = INV:CalculateItemRarity()
        local ITEMPICK = INV:GetDataFromName(box.CONTENTS[pick])
        local RARITYS_OF_ITEM_PICK = ITEMPICK.RARITYS
        print(spins)
    until has_value(RARITYS_OF_ITEM_PICK, rarity)
    tbl.spintable[spins] = { NAME = box.CONTENTS[pick], RARITY = rarity }
end
```

As you can see, there's an outer loop that counts up from one to one hundred, and an inner loop that repeats some code until you're satisfied with the result.