# Is it possible to move the for loop counter in lua?

Tags: memory, lua

I am trying to move my i location forward and backward if a certain string arrives kind of like assembly code, is this possible using lua?

something like this:

```lua
local array = {"Hi", "Goodbye", "Cat"}
for i in pairs(array) do
    if string.find(array[i], "Hi") then 
        move_to(3) -- so it will basically skip over "Goodbye" but I need this on a large scale so it can jump from 3 to 234 and then jump back to 1 etc etc
    elseif array[i] == "Cat" then
        print("Cat")
    end
end
```

Also I cannot just make a variable to check if a jump is in progress and just ignore the other values until I am at the descried location, because then I cannot jump backwards

Thanks!

Comment: What you're describing doesn't seem like a `for` loop any more, but a generic `while (<at-final-location>)` type loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For loops not working completely right Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59847370/for-loops-not-working-completely-right-lua)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a numeric for loop or a generic for loop with the standard iterator functions to do this. You cannot properly control their state from inside. Just use a while loop.

```
while notDoneCondition do
  -- do stuff that may trigger the jumpCondition
  if jumpCondition then
    pos = jumpTarget
  end
end
```